# DataTable won't initiate with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Okay, so I'm trying to make my Bootstrap hover-table work with DataTable. 
I wish to use more of the great features that is part of DataTable. 
As far as I have been able to understand this is what is needed:

```
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="../DataTables-1.10.2/media/js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDNjQueryDataTables194.ashx"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* Table initialisation */
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#sourceTable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

And then of course have a table with the id 'SourceTable':

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover display" cellspacing="0" id="sourceTable">
            <thead>
                ........
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                ........
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                ........
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something must be wrong here, because none of the DataTable features is available in the 'SourceTable' Table.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance

/Mike

EDIT: JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ayq0rk7/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9ayq0rk7/

Comment: Why are you including this url as script? `http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDNjQueryDataTables194.ashx` That url does not contain any script!!

Comment: Must have been a mistake..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay here is working jsfiddle. You are not loading scripts correctly. Load the scripts/css you need from cdn link and not complete page url.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/748aLcxz/2/)

Change:

```
<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/CDNjQueryDataTables194.ashx"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Something else must be ruining my code. 
I see your version working on JSFiddle, but the changes does not help local. 
I'll try to go through the entire code and return with the result. Thanks though.

Comment: Would you recommend I create a new .js file for having the: 
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sourceTable').dataTable();
        });
Or is at the end of the <body> fine?

Comment: Placed it in seperat JS file and now it's working. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Due to my low reputation I can't wote your answer. But I have marked it as the solving answer. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem DonBananMike,Thanks. I'll give you some reputation points. Glad it helped you.